# Performance enhancement when using Direct Query to get data from SQL server in Power BI

Tags: ssas, azure-sql-database, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am using PBI Desktop to create PBIX files which I later upload to Azure Power BI Embedded (PaaS solution). The PBIX gets data from Azure SQL server in Direct Query mode. I want to increase the efficiency of queries that Power BI Embedded sends to SQL for getting my data.

My pbix contains relationships between many tables and RLS (Row Level Security) configured and is taking a lot of time to load. Please advice if the following options will help me increase the efficiency of queries, thus reducing the time taken by the pbix to load: -

1. Using Advanced Options in the Get Data dialog box : Inserting a SQL statement here will get only specific data instead of the entire table. This will reduce the data I see in PBI Desktop, but will it really increase the efficiency of queries sent to SQL for the creation of charts? Eg: Say PBIX needs to create a join between two tables. If I use the advanced options, will the Join be done on reduced data?
2. Using Filters to filter out unwanted rows of the table : Again like above option, this will reduce the data I see in PBI Desktop, but will it really increase the efficiency of queries sent to SQL for the creation of charts? Eg: If I use filters, will the Join be done on reduced data?

**[EDIT - I have added one more option below]**

3. Are the queries for charts on different pages of a PBIX file sent to SQL only when the page is loaded? : If this is true then I can separate my charts into different pages to reduce the number of queries sent at once to SQL.